# Não estou conseguindo calcular os auto valores e auto vetores de uma matriz

Tags: matlab

Como faço para calcular os auto vetores e auto valores de uma matriz no MATLAB?

Answer (score 1):

E so voce usar a funcao `eig`.

Por exemplo, se sua matriz chama `A`:

```
[V, D] = eig(A)
```

`V` e uma matriz que as colunas sao os autovetores pela direita e `D` e uma matriz diagonal com os autovalores.

Mais informacoes na [referencia](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html).

Comment: Como assim pela direita??

Comment: Os autovetores aparecem da equacao 'Av = Lv', o v esta a direita. Se voce fizer ao contrario ele faz pela esquerda e pela esquerda.